# python modify strings in nested lists

Tags: python

I have a strings in nested lists structure, can someone give me a tip on how to modify the strings in a for loop?

For example, I am trying to delete the last couple characters my string these values: `/CLG-MAXFLOW`

If I do

```
example = 'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/36/CLG-MAXFLOW'

print(example[0:36])
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/36'
```

But how can I apply this to strings inside nested lists?

```
devices = [['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/36/CLG-MAXFLOW'],
            ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/38/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/31/CLG-MAXFLOW'],
            ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/21/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/29/CLG-MAXFLOW'],
            ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/25/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/9/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/6/CLG-MAXFLOW'],
            ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/13/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/14/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/30/CLG-MAXFLOW'],
            ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/19/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/8/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/26/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/24/CLG-MAXFLOW'],
            ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/34/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/11/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/27/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/20/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/23/CLG-MAXFLOW'],
            ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/15/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/37/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/39/CLG-MAXFLOW',
            'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/10/CLG-MAXFLOW']]
```

Comment: You can have a nested for loop and use substring or indexing to delete the last few characters.

Comment: Something like `for device in devices`? Any chance you could give me some more tips?

Comment: What do you mean by "apply"? Do you know how to do anything at all with a nested list? Do you know how to do anything at all with an *un*nested list? Where exactly is the conceptual difficulty? When you say that you want to "modify" the strings, what exactly does that mean? Could you show an example of *exactly* what the list should look like *after* the code runs?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Although the question could have been improved, I believe it was 'detailed' enough to understand what the OP wants...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the best solution but worth giving a try:

```
def check_about(lists:list):
    for i,j in enumerate(lists):
        if isinstance(j,list):
            check_about(j)
        else:
            lists[i]=lists[i].strip('/CLG-MAXFLOW')
    return lists
print(check_about(devices))
```

Comment: well that seemed to work thank you it keeps my nested list data structure

Answer (score 1):

If your output must be the same structure given by `devices` variable, but with the string changed, then you can do this:

```
for row in devices:
  for index, string in enumerate(row):
    row[index] = '/'.join(string.split('/')[:-1])
```

Output:

```
[['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/36'],
 ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/38',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/31'],
 ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/21',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/29'],
 ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/25',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/9',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/6'],
 ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/13',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/14',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/30'],
 ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/19',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/8',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/26',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/24'],
 ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/34',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/11',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/27',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/20',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/23'],
 ['slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/15',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/37',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/39',
  'slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/10']]
```